# Is embedding a field using aggregation pipeline before searching and implementing pagination performant in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, nosql-aggregation

I have this use case:

- Search the `Request` collection based on the name of the user who submitted the request, and paginate the returned response

Unfortunately, the `Request` collection does not directly contain the `username` field. Instead, it contains the `userId` field which refers to a `User` document. That `User` document then contains the `username` field.

One approach that directly comes to mind is to embed a duplicate `username` field in the `Request` document that needs to be updated every time the corresponding `User` document's `username` field is updated.

Barring that approach, there are two other approaches I have thought of, but I am not sure what the implications are performance-wise.

1. Approach 1: find the user IDs that match the name given in the query in the `User` document first, then use that `userIds` as filter in the `Request` collection. The disadvantage of this is using the `$in` operator and [the `$in` operator is recommended to only contain tens of values](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#syntax) (which I cannot guarantee will be the case when I search get the user IDs in the `User` document), that can negatively impact performance.
2. Approach 2: embed all the `Request` collection with the `username` field on each request using an aggregation pipeline, then search the embedded documents and apply pagination. I cannot find documentation on how performance is to embed a single string field to all the documents in the `Request` collection. I'm not sure if it is similar to SQL's `SELECT ... JOIN ... WHERE ...` (in the SQL version, this is an acceptable query performance-wise afaik).

What are your thoughts on each of the approach I mentioned. Any docs mentioning the performance (something like the `$in` performance issue) is very welcomed.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you can't use aggregation to query the `User` collection and use `$lookup` to pull in all of the `Request` documents where `Request.userId` matches the `User._id`? That would be one single aggregation query.

Comment: @jQueeny Oh I see. So instead of applying the aggregation pipeline on the `Request` collection to embed the `username` field and search then apply pagination, I will instead apply the aggregation pipeline on the `User` collection, then lookup all `Request` documents that belong to the User?

If I understood correctly, does applying pagination on the `User` collection still allow sorting by `updatedAt` field (or some other fields) from the `Request` collection? And how is it performance-wise compared to the 2 approaches I mentioned? Because what I'm thinking is there's a chance `$lookup`...

Comment: @jQueeny ...might return a lot of `Request` documents for each `User` document.

Comment: @jQueeny On my comment, I meant _does applying aggregation on the `User` collection still allow sorting ... and paginating the `Request` collection_?

Comment: Yes doing the aggregation on the `User` collection and then looking up the `Request` collection is a pretty common approach. You can sort on whatever field you want from the resulting documents but `$sort` has a 100MB memory usage limit which can be written temporarily to disk if it will exceed that limit. Using aggregation you can transform the documents into whichever shape you want and set/unset/project specific fields. What would really help is an example of your aggregation so that someone on SO can advise on optimisation. At the minute its difficult to advise.